List<T>.AddRange throws ArgumentException when passing a ConcurrentDictionary as argument
Today I had a suspicion that the List<T>.AddRange method might not be safe to use with a concurrent collection as argument, so I made an experiment to find out:
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dictionary = new();

for (int i = 1; i <= 50_000; i++)
    dictionary.TryAdd(i, default);

List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> list = new();

Thread thread = new(() =>
{
    for (int i = -1; i >= -50_000; i--)
        dictionary.TryAdd(i, default);
});
thread.Start();

list.AddRange(dictionary); // Throws

thread.Join();
Console.WriteLine($"dictionary.Count: {dictionary.Count:#,0}, list.Count: {list.Count:#,0}");

Online demo.
The ConcurrentDictionary is initialized with 50,000 positive keys. Then 50,000 additional negative keys are added on a different thread, concurrently with adding the dictionary in the list with the AddRange method. I was expecting that eventually the dictionary would have 100,000 keys, and the list somewhere between 50,000 and 100,000 items. In reality I got an ArgumentException:
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The index is equal to or greater than the length of the array, or the number of elements in the dictionary is greater than the available space from index to the end of the destination array.
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair`2[] array, Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Program.Main()

My question is: Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it from happening? Is there any way to ensure that the list.AddRange(dictionary); line will be always successful, with no exceptions thrown?
Imagine that the dictionary might have been given to me as an IEnumerable<T>, and I have no idea about its underlying type. The same exception is thrown in this case as well:
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> enumerable = dictionary;
list.AddRange(enumerable); // Throws

This behavior reduces my confidence about using the List<T>.AddRange API in general.
Context: A similar symptom is mentioned in this question, but a minimal and reproducible example is not provided, so I am not sure that the scenario is the same. Another related question is this, about calling the LINQ ToList on a ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>. Nevertheless the documentation warns about using extension methods on concurrent collections, but I am not seeing any warning against using a concurrent collection with the List<T>.AddRange method.

However, members accessed through one of the interfaces the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> implements, including extension methods, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be synchronized by the caller.

@shingo do you mean that I am not supposed to pass the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> to the AddRange method, because the argument of this method is IEnumerable<T>?

Not only that, because there is no clue to indicate AddRange is thread-safe, it should be avoided.

@shingo in my example I am not using the List<T> concurrently. All operations on the List<T> are invoked on the main thread of the console application. What I am using concurrently is the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>, which is designed to be used this way.

Let me rephrase my word: there is no clue to indicate that AddRange will use thread-safe methods. For ConcurrentDictionary, the document warns that accessing through interface is not thread-safe, while AddRange accepts an interface. So, it can be concluded that calling AddRange does not guarantee thread safety.

@shingo would you advise against using the List<T>.AddRange in general, or only in combination with the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> in particular?

What's happening is fairly straightforward.
List<T>.AddRange has a check to see whether the thing it was passed is an ICollection<T>. If so, it can optimize by using ICollection<T>.Count to allocate enough space for the new range in one go (instead of potentially resizing the list multiple times), and ICollection<T>.CopyTo to copy the collection's elements in one go, instead of adding them one-by-one.
The code is here:
if (collection is ICollection<T> c)
{
    int count = c.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        if (_items.Length - _size < count)
        {
            Grow(checked(_size + count));
        }

        c.CopyTo(_items, _size);
        _size += count;
        _version++;
    }
}

ConcurrentDictionare<TKey, TValue> implements ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, and its implementations of Count and CopyTo are safe in themselves, but there's no inherent synchronization between them.
So List<T>.AddRange asks the dictionary for its size, allocates that number of new elements, then asks the dictionary to copy itself into that newly-allocated space. However, the dictionary has grown by that point, and throws an exception here:
int count = GetCountNoLocks();
if (array.Length - count < index)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.ConcurrentDictionary_ArrayNotLargeEnough);
}

As for who's to "blame" here, I'm not sure. The optimization which List<T> is doing is sensible most of the time, and as a non-thread-safe collection it's not trying to be thread-safe. As @shingo notes,  ConcurrentDictionary doesn't guarantee thread-safety when accessed through one of its interfaces, although it does its best. ICollection<T>.CopyTo is documented as throwing if the space it's being asked to copy into isn't large enough.
As for workarounds, the simplest and most obviously correct is to create an intermediate collection: list.AddRange(dict.ToArray()). However, this of course comes with the cost of an intermediate allocation, which may be large.
You could also wrap loop over the dictionary and use Add with each element (ConcurrentDictionary's GetEnumerator() is thread-safe), and this is effectively what you're expecting AddRange to do anyway.
I think in general you just need to be careful when mixing thread-safe and non-thread-safe types in this way. Make sure that you understand exactly what's going on, and exactly what thread-safe guarantees the types involved do and don't make.

Thanks canton7 for the answer. I think that you've explained the cause of the problem pretty well. Do you have any suggestion about how to alleviate the problem? Maybe stop using the List<T>.AddRange with arguments of unknown origin?

@TheodorZoulias I've added some commentary to the bottom

@TheodorZoulias One could also just loop through the dictionary and use Add instead. ConcurrentDictionary.GetEnumerator is safe to use, according to the documentation. While this may grow the list multiple times, it can be somewhat mitigated with doing EnsureCapacity first.

@Sweeper True, that's better than my Select(x => x) suggesting. Edited to add.

Canton the ToArray works if I invoke it on the dictionary directly, but if the dictionary is passed to me as an IEnumerable<T> then it fails in a similar way (demo). I guess I should choose a different workaround depending on the situation.

Yes: Enumerable.ToArray() will do the same trick with ICollection<T>. ConcurrentDictionary.ToArray however is documented as being safe

Ultimately, threading is hard. We can do a lot of things to cover up some of the hard bits, but fundamentally it's a tricky thing to do, and you need to carefully understand everything that's going on.

Canton the issue is that I am not using the List<T> concurrently. The only questionable thing that I am doing in my demo is passing the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> as argument in a method with parameter of type IEnumerable<T>. I guess I am not supposed to do that. Probably the warning in the docs includes this case as well.

@TheodorZoulias The issue is that List is not accessing ConcurrentDictionary in a way which is thread-safe. The thread-safe collections are only thread-safe when used in particular ways, which is documented. I would not expect a non-thread-safe collection to know how to safely access a thread-safe collection. Using a thread-safe collection does not guarantee that your code is now thread-safe: it's very easy to do things with a thread-safe collection which break thread-safety. Threading is still hard.

Canton I agree that threading is hard, but it shouldn't be impossible for people to write correct multithreaded code if they read the documentation and they are careful. My sense is that the warning in the documentation about not accessing members of the ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> through one of the interfaces it implements, might not communicate strongly enough that the collection should not be passed as argument in methods with IEnumerable<T> parameter.

You're welcome to raise an issue with the docs team about that, but it's not something which I can help with unfortunately!

Canton honestly I am not particularly inclined to do it either. :-)

As an addendum to Canton7's answer, you can "hide" the type from the optimisation that causes the problem by using a method like this:
public static IEnumerable<T> Enumerate<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}

Then you can call: list.AddRange(Enumerate(dictionary)); and it won't throw an exception. This will avoid having to make a copy of the collection.

I had something similar to this as a suggestion in my answer, but removed it on the grounds that using a loop with Add was clearer and slightly more performant.

Thanks Matthew for the answer. I could have accepted your answer as well, but Canton answered first. :-)

Canton's was the correct answer IMO, this was just supplemental information that wouldn't fit in a comment.
